# How can I programmatically get the admin theme

Tags: 8, theming

Similar question to [How can I programmatically get the theme name?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/203312/3167) and [How do I programmatically change the admin theme?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/235528/3167).

I want to simply obtain  the current admin theme machine name and human name, even when I might not be on a page where the admin theme is enabled as the active theme.

This information doesn't appear to be directly accessible via the [ThemeManager](https://api.drupal.org/ThemeManager) class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is config and you can get it with the following snippet.

```
$admin_theme = \Drupal::config('system.theme')->get('admin');
$admin_theme_name = \Drupal::service('theme_handler')->getName($admin_theme);
```

Or with Drush:

```
drush cget system.theme admin
```